# Inline assembly printf interpreting integers as an address

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to make an array printing by the inline assembly. Printf function keeps interpreting value on the stack as an address it needs to print out and results in an error (Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r692d3). And if I pass the address to the printf, then it prints out garbage values like those: (Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r691de).
Also, if someone knows - how to put a `'\n'` inside a string with inline ASM? Thanks :)

```
int main()
{
    int mas[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int32_t diff = sizeof(int);
    __asm
    {
        mov esi, 0x0

        lea ecx, [mas]
        mov eax, [ecx]
        push ecx
        call printf; Here it tries to read value '1' as an address
        pop eax

        loop_t:

        xor ebx, ebx; Clear the registers
        xor ecx, ecx;

            lea ecx, [mas]; ECX = &mas
            mov ebx, diff;
        add ebx, ecx; &mas + diff
        mov eax, [ebx]; Transfer the value
        push eax; Push it on stack
        call printf; Same thing here, interprets it as an address
            pop eax;
            add diff, 0x4;
            inc esi; Cleanup process and looping back on
            cmp esi, 0x5;
            jne loop_t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of the `printf` function is the format string, i.e. a pointer to the first character of a null terminated character array. Therefore, the first parameter will always be treated as an address.

If you pass the value 1 as the first parameter to printf (by pushing it onto the stack last), then it will try to read the format string from the address 1 (which will fail).

Comment: That is strange. Because in simple cases like if pushing const char value  on stack, it reads prints it correctly

Comment: @Raicha: By "pushing const char value on the stack", you mean that you are actually pushing a single ASCII code **value** onto the stack, not the address of the `char`?

Comment: Const char* is address

Comment: @Raicha: But in your first comment, you wrote "const char value", not "const char *"? Was that a mistake?

Comment: @Raicha: If you are passing a simple string (address to the first element of a null terminated character array) as the first parameter to printf, then this will likely work, because it is treated as a format string. It is like writing `printf( "This is a string" );` instead of `printf( "%s", "This is a string" );` This won't work if the string contains formatting characters, such as '%'. In that case, you must escape these formatting characters with two '%'.